# Spring Data JPA mapping one-to-one relationship returns null value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am making a Spring Boot backend, and I have the following problem. When I get a `Software` from `VersionableFileRepository` and call the `getSystem` function on that I get the actual `System` within the relationship. But when I get a `Documentation` from `VersionableFileRepository` its `getSystem` function returns `null`. I handle the `Software` and `Documentation` in the same way, and all instance of these have a `System`.

Illustrated with code:

`versionableFileRepository.findById(fileId).get().getSystem()` returns a valid `System` when `fileId` identify a `Software` and returns null when a `Documentation`

What's wrong? Did I mess something up in the implementation?

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class System {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "software_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Software software;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "documentation_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Documentation documentation;

    //other fields, getters and setters...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class VersionableFile {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "file", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FileVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();

    public abstract System getSystem();

    public abstract void setSystem(System system);

    //getters and setters...

}
```

```
@Entity
public class Software extends VersionableFile {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "software")
    @JsonIgnore
    private System system;

    @Override
    public System getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSystem(System system) {
        this.system = system;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Documentation extends VersionableFile {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "documentation")
    @JsonIgnore
    private System system;

    @Override
    public System getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSystem(System system) {
        this.system = system;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface VersionableFileRepository extends CrudRepository<VersionableFile, Long> {
}
```

**Database:**

Everything looks good in the database, this is the `system` table:
[image: system table]

And the corresponding objects can be found in the other two tables (`software` and `documentation`). Furthermore the appropriate constraints are also defined.

I think this is a JPA issue, because when I get a `System` object from `SystemRepository` (not mentioned here) it has the right `software` and `documentation` fields.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: post what exactly exist in your database as well. If it does not exist or it is malformed then it is not a JPA issue

Comment: thanks for the comment, I made up for it

Answer (score 0):

Have already commented but looking better I think I found something major here.

**Proposal 1**

Your Entities structure seems good to me. However you have a major Issue with your java code to retrieve those entities back from database.

```
versionableFileRepository.findById(fileId).get().getSystem()
```

`fileId` as well as `documentId` are plain Long numbers. How would JPA know if you want to retrieve a Software or a Documentation? This will not work. As you have constructed it, it will have separate tables Documentation and Software and each one of those will have a column Id as primary key.

Make it easier for JPA by using specific repositories

```
@Repository
public interface SoftwareRepository extends CrudRepository<Software, Long> {
}
```

Then to retrieve software just use `softwareRepository.findById(id).get().getSystem()`

And

```
@Repository
    public interface DocumentationRepository extends CrudRepository<Documentation, Long> {
    }
```

Then to retrieve documentation just use `documentationRepository.findById(id).get().getSystem()`

**Proposal 2**

If you wish to go along the way you are going then I would consider that the error is specifically on your ids that are generated. You want different tables in your case Documentation and Software to have distinct Ids. Then JPA could distinct from the Id what entity you have.

To achieve that you have to change the strategy of generating Ids

```
public abstract class VersionableFile {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;

     ....
```

Comment: Thank you for the advices! I made the recommended changes but unfortunately it still doesn't work now.

Comment: then paste a screenshot of your database records. Maybe there something is malfunctioning

Comment: I have modified the question. It now contains this information. The software and document table also have the corresponding records.